# Обрезка ссылки и добавление в неё нужных символов

Tags: python

Имеется ссылка `https://example.com/136B?s1=f64611f761ead4f0c9795794229475&s2=155895`
Нужно добавить в ссылку символ 's' чтобы получилось такая ссылка: `https://example.com/s/136B?s1=f64611f761ead4f0c9795794229475&s2=155895` — и обрезать ссылку, чтобы получилось так: `https://example.com/s/136B`.
Вся проблема заключается в том, что ссылки меняются, и завтра к примеру может быть не
`https://example.com/`, а `https://examplee.com/` или что то другое (с большими символами в ссылке).

Comment: используйте регулярные выражения

Comment: a = s[:s.rindex('/')+1]+'s/'+s[s.rindex('/')+1:]

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помог)